# I want to make it possible : concat string and variables with locator in Selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, relative-locators

Here is the task we have to resolve.
Scenario :
1> Every time user opens the test, he must be asked to input date and month.

2> Those scanned inputs variables d1 and m1 called by method esi

3> id element with that month and date must be seen clicked on website in date section based on user input.
The of id for all dates is something like :

**Tag div** , **id** = **bkmgFlights_travelDates_1-date-2022-10-21** ,
in which start is always same for all dates as **bkmgFlights_travelDates_1-date-2022-**

So I have already done the  1> and 2> successfully,
for the 3rd task, I am trying the below, but not working.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'bkmgFlights_travelDates_1-date-2022-')]"+esi.m1+"-"+esi.d1)).click();
```

I also tried action class,  concat is happening as i can see colours and no errors, but still not working. It shows invalid selector, sometimes shows differet errors with action class, when I try

```
action1.click(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//div[contains(@id,'bkmgFlights_travelDates_1-date-2022-')]"+esi.m1+"-"+esi.d1)));
```

Please help me with how we can locate elements based on path + concatenated string and variable and then at last performing click on it.
Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5CXJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
string locator = String.format("//div[contains(@id,'bkmgFlights_travelDates_1-date-2022-%s-%s')]", esi.m1, esi.d1);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator)).click();
```

If you want to learn more about string interpolation from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-to-illustrate-string-interpolation/), if you wish.